# Why won't my rails server work in cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

My ruby on rails server suddenly stopped working (Cloud9, Mac OS). This is the error msg I keep getting:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:34:in `parse!': missing argument: -p (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:293:in `parse_options'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:184:in `options'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:60:in `set_environment'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:44:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've tried everything I could find on here but no luck. Apologies if this solution is on here somewhere. Here's my Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]

# Use postgresql as the database for production
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
# Use bootstrap library for styles
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1'
# Use font awesome library for icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.2.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0',          group: :doc
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
# Use devise for user auth
gem 'devise', '~>3.4.1'
# Use stripe for handling payments
gem 'stripe', '1.16.1'
# Use figaro to hide secret keys
gem 'figaro', '1.0.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: What command are you running that produces this error?

Comment: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT -b $IP

Comment: 'bundle exec rails server -p $PORT -b $IP' (w/ out the last dash). Also I figured it out. Something to do with a typo in a user file I created. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In cloud9 (as opposed to nitrous ;) you start your server with `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`